# How can I get the total sum of all numbers in a csv column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, data-analysis

I am trying to do some quick data analysis of a spreadsheet. One of the columns is titled "Total[s]": It has a list of different money totals going down the column. I would like to get the final total of all the totals in this CSV file.

Here is my python "code" so far:

```
from pandas import *

data = read_csv('data.csv')

total = data['Total'].tolist()

final = sum(map(float,total))

print(final)
```

This is outside my normal python understanding. I usually only work on automation. So I have no idea if I'm close to what I want, or not?

Just trying to get my toes wet with pandas. Anything helps!

Comment: Do you mean `final = data['Total'].sum()`? Could you provide a sample of `data.csv` to make your provided code snippet runnable?

Comment: Total
189.05
999.5
179.64
539.73
167.44
299.4
149.25
449.1
63.68
539.4
449.1
57.71
1,619.19
174.65
250

Comment: Maybe then `data = read_csv('filename.csv', thousands=',')` then `final = data['Total'].sum()` should work fine.

Comment: The data I imputed is:

Total
189.05
999.5
179.64
539.73
167.44

Doing your code the total was:

19627.880000000005

Doing it with a calculator the total was:

2,075.36

Do you know how I can get the same output as the calculator? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: It works on me. `data = [189.05, 999.5, 179.64, 539.73, 167.44]` and then `pd.Series(data).sum()`. It gave me `2075.36`

Comment: Your code looks very close.  Sure there are other ways to do it.  You are doing a lot in one statement, which could be broken into steps that you could display the value of to ensure every conversion you are doing is as imagined.  I don't know about the commas in the data though...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  'id': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno'],
  'money': [189.05, 999.5, 179.64, 539.73, 167.44]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

That will give us:

```
>>> df

    id   money
0   abc  189.05
1   def  999.50
2   ghi  179.64
3   jkl  539.73
4   mno  167.44
```

To sum the `money` column:

```
final = df['money'].sum()
```

The `final` will give us:

```
>>> final
2075.36
```

CSV, excel, dictionary shouldn't affect the sum method. Here is a screenshot using `pd.read_csv()` and the result.

[image: using read_csv]

Comment: How do I do it if the data is coming from a CSV file? I would like to find a way to not have to manually make a list. Is there a way to convert a table column into a list?

Comment: Same thing. The list I did is just to illustrate. You just need to do `df = pd.read_csv('filename_here.csv')` instead of `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`.

Comment: It works dictionary in python, as you did. But it won't work when extracting from a csv Column. Python tries to sum each number individually and not as a collective. Your answer works, just not for a csv file for some reason. :/

Comment: Can you post sample  (with dummy data) of your CSV on your original thread? The code I provided should work for CSV/Excel/etc for numeric column/series.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with the decimal point in place? I will be given a bunch of CSV files and I want the formula to always work with the files I gave me. I don't want to go in and take away all the decimal points. The company I work for will have the decimal points in place on every CSV. Thanks for being close! Just need to solve that one last problem.

Comment: Link to spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uWiQ5wNlI2LGVnV3z1RuOXSmyipODpYy0zjTkL7xxtE/edit?usp=sharing